# A-Frame "start experience" button

Tags: aframe

I want to create a start experience like button on my A-Frame design. My experience needs to hide until you press a button and then it appears

Comment: Did you try anything ? It could be easier if we knew how did you try to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

**1) Hide the a-frame `scene` until a html button is pressed**

This one is simple. Bring a white `<div>` up front (by setting up a high `z-index`), and hide it (`display: none`) when a button is clicked.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5926hd7e/1/).

**2) Hide the experience content "in-game"**

This one is a bit harder. Hide the `a-camera` within a white sphere with a button, and hide the sphere, when the button is clicked.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5926hd7e/2/)