# A-frame: scene with intro and a "start" button

Tags: aframe

I'm new to A-frame (and a novice coder, indeed).

I'm trying to set up an intro to my scene, with a minimum UI (a "start experience" button).

This particular question have been asked before [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895498/a-frame-start-experience-button), but I'm unfamiliar to Fiddle.

I've been using Glitch as a code playground and I can't figure out how to run theses solutions outside Fiddle.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to hide the `a-frame` canvas is to place a `<div>` element in front with some content - text, pictures, start button.

The `div` needs to be fixed, and remeber to set it's with and height to a maximum.

```
#loading {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 10000; /* overkill, but keeps the div in front */
}
```

---

As for the fiddle part, most of the time you can just copy 
a) the **HTML** part to your `<body>` element.
b) the **JS** part to any included `.js` script .
c) the **CSS** part to any included `.css` stylesheet.

Check it out on [this](https://glitch.com/~aframe-introbutton) glitch.